# Kubernetes yaml not working on Rabbitmq cluster

Tags: azure, kubernetes, rabbitmq

I have a Rabbitmq Kubernetes cluster version 3.10.2 running on Azure AKS. I have applied cluster operator using.

```
kubectl apply -f "https://github.com/rabbitmq/cluster-operator/releases/latest/download/cluster-operator.yml"
```

Now I have created a rabbitmq using below Yaml

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-dev
---
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: RabbitmqCluster
metadata:
  name: rabbitmq-dev
  namespace: rabbitmq-dev
spec:
  replicas: 1
  rabbitmq:
    additionalPlugins:
      - rabbitmq_stream
    additionalConfig: |
      default_user=admin
      default_pass=##########
  persistence:
    storageClassName: default
    storage: "30Gi"
  resources:
    requests:
      cpu: 500m
      memory: 1Gi
    limits:
      cpu: 1
      memory: 1Gi
  service:
    type: ClusterIP
```

Everything is running fine. Now I want to create a vhost on rabbitmq cluster. Using this document. [Document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/kubernetes/operator/using-operator.html)

```
---
apiVersion: rabbitmq.com/v1beta1
kind: Vhost
metadata:
  name: datamgmt-dev-vhost
  namespace: rabbitmq-dev
spec:
  name: dev1
  rabbitmqClusterReference:
    name: rabbitmq-dev
```

It is applied successfully. and I can see in **kubectl** command.

```
NAME                                    AGE
vhost.rabbitmq.com/datamgmt-dev-vhost   1d
```

But not able to see in vhost rabbitmq UI url in admin page.